# What is a row in talend and how do contexts behave inside them?

Tags: java, esb, talend

Just a few questions to gain a deeper understanding of Talend ESB. Once a job is running, from what I understand you get a row for each time the job is run.

I guess, my first question is, is that correct? That each row is a separate container for its own lifetime or can rows interfere with each other if two run at once?

Next question would be around contexts variables and whether or not if these are changed at run time (`context.var1 = "blah";`) do they affect the job as a whole or only the currently running row?

Related question on Talend not answered here - https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=162414#p162414

Comment: What I've seen from the logs, and the ESB job behaviour, you are correct. Each "request" results in a new process, If you have 100 requests that will result in 100 processes. This way it can scale really well.

Comment: @BalazsGunics - Okay, thats great, so do you know if that would that mean for each of those 100 requests the context variables are set the defaults that they were when the job started? Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: Yes, it will be default. Even globalMap works the same way, when you call a thread out of your job, it will get a snapshot of the globalMap, and the threads see different content for the same variable in the globalMap.

Comment: @BalazsGunics - Ahh fantastic, so just to make sure I understand... This means that there is no chance that one "request" that is running at exactly the same time as many other "requests" could interfere with the other requests context variables? - Providing the context variables are set at the beginning of the job?

Comment: You are correct, every execution will have its own process with unique, globalMap / context

Answer (score 0):

A row is the connection type in Talend. A Row connection handles the actual data. The Row connections can be main, lookup, reject or output according to the nature of the flow processed.

For deeper understanding please visit this [link](https://help.talend.com/reader/rK3ZCi0d2W4A2wGBCtdupg/NMzxcG7WNK7Ym7Ei6HkVHg)

The answer of your second question would be, if you change the value of context variable at run time it will be changed for current job which is running not only for the currently running row.

There is one important thing to notice that, changing the value of context variable at run time will not change it's value in any associated job(connected via tRunJob component and if both job shares the same context variable.)

To achieve this you can pass the changed value of context variable in Context Param field of basic settings tab of tRunJob component.